# Reviews Audits: Are Repeat Failers Audited More Often?

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I've just been allowed to review again after a month banning; I'm not proud of it, but 
it was totally my own fault. I used to review every day in my lunch break in work, so I used to clear a good deal of reviews in a week period and being in a work environment, distraction from the reviews was a common occurrence.

Good news is, I've stopped this now... I've served my time!

In my first 20 Suggested Edit reviews, I was audited about 6 times. I passed all, but I was just curious of the frequency, as I remember them only occurring perhaps once or twice in a set of 20 reviews prior to my banning.

This could be due to one of three things:

1. Review Audits occur more often for repeat offenders (unfortunately, I'm part of this group)
2. Pure coincidence (being the nature of 'random' checks)
3. The frequency of Review Audits has increased globally in my month 'off'

If the first one isn't the case, is it worth adding this as a feature request? I'd be all for it!

If the first one is indeed the case, how long can I expect the higher volume reviews and I've 'proved my worth' to the system?

Comment: I do think the audits come more for those with weaker statistics of failing them; no reference on that. I'm not sure I've ever heard that being review banned is directly related; but the stats would correlate for that purpose instead. And kudos for working to improve!

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks for this... I'd really love to know more about how this works!

Comment: i dont think the audit system is THAT complicated...

Comment: My ban will finish in a few hours, I'll see how it goes for me.

Comment: So I've been through the first day of my post 30-day ban review activity and haven't noticed too many audits.